# How is the field of view of a telescope related to the diameter, D, and focal ratio, f/,of the telescope?

Tags: optics, astronomy, lenses, telescopes

The question specifically relates to a Cassegrain reflector with a CCD at focus.

Given the plate scale $\propto \frac{1}{f}$ and therefore $\propto\frac{1}{Df}$ with units of $\frac{arcsec}{mm}$ it would make sense that

field of view = platescale$^2 \times$ area$^2$

field of view $\propto\frac{1}{f^2}$

However in my notes I have that the field of view of a telescope $\propto \frac{f}{D}$ and so field of view $\propto f$

Which (if either) is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The larger the focal length of the lens, the smaller the FOV - you are looking at a smaller and smaller part of space as you magnify your image more.

Obviously when you use a bigger sensor, that increases your FOV - but since the magnification of a telescope is only determined by its focal length, the FOV must decrease with focal length.